# Dojo DnD Programmatically Select Node(s)

Tags: javascript, dojo, drag-and-drop

Does anyone know if there is a way to programmatically select a node (by id, for example)?  I've been looking over the documentation and see the following methods:

getSelectedNodes() — returns a NodeList of selected DOM nodes.

selectNone() — remove the selection from all items. It returns the selector object itself for easy chaining of calls.

selectAll() — selects all items. It returns the selector object itself for easy chaining of calls.

deleteSelectedNodes()

But there isn't a method to select nodes (accept during node insertion - but in my case, the nodes are already inserted).  It'd be great if there was a selectNodes(), or selectNodeById() method.

Does anyone know of a undocumented method, or otherwise have a work-around?

Comment: Dojo Drag and Drop - which node are you talking about ? Is it related to Dojo tree - Programatically selecting Dojo tree node ?

Comment: I was referring to the basic Dojo drang-and-drop, not the Dojo tree.  A node would be the draggable html elements.  But, it is probably similar in concept to the tree.